# Shell Script to check value in simple typescript file

Tags: linux, typescript, macos, shell

I have a simple TS file

**env.ts**

Which contains

```
export const BUILD_SDK = false 
export const DUMMY_PRESET = false
```

and I have build.sh script which builds our SDk.

I want to write a **shell script** (build.sh) which throws an error if value in env.ts is false before building.

Can someone please help me out in figuring out a way to do it?

### Update based on the answer from Flashtube

So I tried this

```
#!/bin/bash
# With head -n 2 env.ts we get the first line of env.ts
# With cut -d " " we split the line at every space
# With -f 5 we specify we want the 5th spit value, in this case the boolean value
# If that is equals to true, we echo an error and pipe it to the error output with  1>&2 and exit with exit status 64
if [[ $(head -n 2 App/env/index.tsx | cut -d " " -f 5) = "false" ]]; then 
    echo "Error! check env variables and set it to true" 1>&2;
    exit 64;
fi
```

Where my env file looks like this

```
//Please inform if you do any changes in this file so that we can update build script
export const SDK_BUILD = false
```

but this didn't work

Comment: You probably have to use the tsc compiler and load the output, then do some more tricky stuff. I would advise you to use something like dotenv in stead: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv the dotenv-concep has support in many languages, and you don't have to make your own custom crazy thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether any const of a set of specific consts is false, you can do it in bash this way:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/path/to/file/env.ts"
CONST_TO_CHECK="(BUILD_SDK|DUMMY_PRESET)"

if grep -Eq 'export\s*const\s*'"${CONST_TO_CHECK}"'\s*=\s*false' "$FILE"; then
  echo "Error"
fi
```

Simply add your const names to `CONST_TO_CHECK`, separated with a pipe.

If you want to see whether any const of a long list of consts is false, use this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/path/to/file/env.ts"
CONST_NAME_REGEX='[a-zA-Z_]*'

if grep -Eq 'export\s*const\s*'"${CONST_NAME_REGEX}"'\s*=\s*false' "$FILE"; then
  echo "Error"
fi
```

Here you might need to update `CONST_NAME_REGEX` to reflect you naming conventions.

Comment: This is the way to go. I have too little knowledge about grep to throw out a command like that x)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following bash script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# With head -n 1 env.ts we get the first line of env.ts
# With cut -d " " we split the line at every space
# With -f 5 we specify we want the 5th spit value, in this case the boolean value
# If that is equals to true, we echo an error and pipe it to the error output with  1>&2 and exit with exit status 64
if [[ $(head -n 1 env.ts | cut -d " " -f 5) = "false" ]]; then 
    echo "Error!" 1>&2;
    exit 64;
fi
```

Now we can detect wheter the value is false or true.

Comment: what if I want to check two env? (in question, code snippet)? `export const DUMMY_PRESET = false`? I tried `-n 2` but that didn't work